# Python - filename and foldername comparison

Tags: python

I have many files xxxxxxAB123, xxxxAB124, xxxxAB125 , xxxxAB126 ... I need to move these files to their respective folders based on file name , for example file xxxxxAB123 should be moved to folder AB123 , file xxxxAB124 should be moved to folder AB124 ,and so on ... How do I achieve this in python ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all filenames have the same pattern (e.g., whatever comes at the front, ends with AB###) you can split the latter part, make a directory with that, and then move the file into the directory.

Try the code below:

```
import os
import shutil

directory = "path/to/files"
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    dirName = file[-5:] # retrieves the last 5 characters in the filename.
    try: 
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(directory, dirName))
    except OSError:
        pass
    shutil.move(os.path.join(directory, file), os.path.join(directory, dirName))
```

Comment: the folders already exist, no need to make new, how to modify it?

Comment: @Jeff If you already have the folders, you can remove the try-except sequence which makes a directory.